# cascading relational models Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models

`User` `has_many :articles`

`Article` `has_many :daily_view_metrics` & `belongs_to :user`

`DailyViewMetric` `belongs_to :article`

I want each user to have an overview of the metrics for their articles. At the moment I pass `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in the `show` action of the users controller to open a specific users's show page. I also pass in `@articles = Article.where(user_id: params[:id]).load` in order to limit the available articles to only the user's articles.

Since the `DailyViewMetric` model has the same article multiple times (at different days) I need to aggregate them into a new array of arrays. I.e. I need

```
article_id  date   views
1           feb-01  20
1           feb-02  50
2           feb-01  30
```

to be returned as [[1,70],[2,30]] so I can sort it according to user wishes. How do I do this? Do I make a named scope in the `DailyViewMetric` model? or in the `user_helper.rb`?

It would be nice if I could have something that I can run `newArray.each do |a|` on in my view to make a table with stuff like `<%= a.article_id %>` and `<%= sumviews %>`, etc.. with something I can pass in the user_id so the aggregate is limited to his/her articles

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in the following way

Long form:

views_array = []

```
@articles.each do |a|
 a.views do |v|
  views_array << [a.id, v.date, v.count]
 end
end
```

Short form:

```
@articles.collect {|a| a.daily_view_metrics.collect {|dv| [a.id, dv.date, dv.count] } }
```

Comment: that actually doesn't aggregate it. I still get a 2d array like this `[1,feb-01,20],[1,feb-02,50],[2,....]]`

Comment: isn't that what you need? Can you paste the output of what you're getting. (it should be an array of arrays as I understood)

Comment: yes it should be an array of arrays, but the aggregate i.e. look at the `id` and add all the views together and give one element of the array that is [id, date, sum_of_views]. I need this to be able to sort  the table properly since currently if I sort by views it sorts it by the article that has the highest views on a day as opposed to the highest total number of views.

Comment: essentially I want to run a `mapreduce` on the dataset

Comment: do you mean sum the count? I thought that what daily_view_metrics has in it.  if daily view metric has many rows for a date, you could use reduce  [1,2,3].reduce(:+). That will essentially give you the count. So you'd need to get an array of counts in that case and apply reduce to it.

Comment: I need a sum of the integer that's in the views column (i.e. if one day has 20 views and the other has 50 views I want the final array to have 70 in its `views` field for that article). I'll look into the reduce method and let you know if that works

Comment: `.reduce` seems like what I need, can you give me a tip on how I get that started so that I get this started? The value I want to group it around is the `id` value. i.e. -> for [id,date,views] `[1,2014-02-01,10],[1,2014-02-02,20],[2,2014-02-05,25]` --> `[1,2014-02-01,30],[2,2014-02-05,25]`

Comment: paste me what you have at the moment to work with. I lost track about what you have to being with. Do you have a collection of some sort? If so, what does that look like? [1,2014-02-01,10],[1,2014-02-02,20],[2,2014-02-05,25]  ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49264/discussion-between-killerpixler-and-lsaffie)